# Linker Command Failed With Exit Code 1 after reopening Xcode

Tags: linker-errors, xcode7

My code is not working for some reason. I didn't change the name of the project or anything, this just happened all of a sudden. I'm not sure what happened but I really need my simulator to work!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by deleting a framework in my project's folders. I guess it was a duplicate.